# store not is defined when createStore is execute in async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In redux store, is it possible to load different set of reducers into one single store? My attempt failed

```
import userReducers from './reducers'
import adminReducers from './reducers/admin'

//share reducer btw member and admin
let store
getUserRole().then(role => {
   reducers =  role === 'member'
   ? userReducers
   : adminReducers
   console.log('reducers', reducers) 
   store =  createStore(
       reducers,
       composeWithDevTools(
           applyMiddleware(thunk)
       )
   )
})

export default store
```

I've also created a miniature to demo the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n5r445nnom

Comment: Why don't you keep separate reducers for those roles? Or in the same reducer, with different properties?

Comment: @devserkan client app and admin app don't share reducers, they are totally different thing, there's no point to load admin reducer when client is logged in, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

read this answer very carefully

[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

so basically the code in `then` function runs after the `undefined store` has been exported and used in other file

to check this you can also add one console.log in then function after store is being set

Comment: so how to export a defined `store`?